# How to use JavaScript library installed with npm in Symfony

Tags: symfony, npm, node-modules, assetic

I have installed multiple JS libraries with npm and I trying to use them in Symfony views.

```
<script src="{{ asset('path/to/js.js') }}"></script>
```

Do I have to install node modules in web directory ? Is it a good practice ?

What's the best way to achieve that ?

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html

Comment: I already read the documentation, but is it is very confusing. How I am supposed to import and use library installed with node ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using [Gulp](https://gulpjs.com/) to compile your assets into minified JS/CSS files. It can installed via npm, run from command line and good documentation exists including specifically how to gulp npm installed files.

Here's a sample of my Gulpfile so you can see how to gulp npm files:

```
var paths = {
    admin: {
        js: [
            'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
            'node_modules/semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.js',
            'vendor/sylius/sylius/src/Sylius/Bundle/AdminBundle/Resources/private/js/**',
            'vendor/sylius/sylius/src/Sylius/Bundle/UiBundle/Resources/private/js/**',
            'vendor/sylius/sylius/src/Sylius/Bundle/ShippingBundle/Resources/public/js/**',
            'vendor/sylius/sylius/src/Sylius/Bundle/PromotionBundle/Resources/public/js/sylius-promotion.js',
            'vendor/sylius/sylius/src/Sylius/Bundle/UserBundle/Resources/public/js/sylius-user.js'
        ],
        sass: [
            'vendor/sylius/sylius/src/Sylius/Bundle/UiBundle/Resources/private/sass/**',
        ],
        css: [
            'node_modules/semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css'
        ],
        img: [
            'vendor/sylius/sylius/src/Sylius/Bundle/UiBundle/Resources/private/img/**',
        ]
    },
    shop: {
        js: [
            'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
            'node_modules/semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.js',
            'vendor/sylius/sylius/src/Sylius/Bundle/UiBundle/Resources/private/js/**',
            'vendor/sylius/sylius/src/Sylius/Bundle/ShopBundle/Resources/private/js/**'
        ],
        sass: [
            'vendor/sylius/sylius/src/Sylius/Bundle/UiBundle/Resources/private/sass/**',
            'vendor/sylius/sylius/src/Sylius/Bundle/ShopBundle/Resources/private/scss/**',
        ],
        css: [
            'node_modules/semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css',
            'vendor/fortawesome/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css'
        ],
        fonts: [
            'vendor/fortawesome/font-awesome/fonts/**.*'
        ],
        img: [
            'vendor/sylius/sylius/src/Sylius/Bundle/UiBundle/Resources/private/img/**',
        ],
        app: [
            'src/AppBundle/Resources/private/scss/**',
        ],
        appJs: [
            'src/AppBundle/Resources/private/js/**',
        ],
    }
};

gulp.task('admin-js', function () {
    return gulp.src(paths.admin.js)
        .pipe(concat('app.js'))
        .pipe(gulpif(env === 'prod', uglify))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(adminRootPath + 'js/'))
    ;
});
```